# Any equivalent function to pthread_getcpuclockid since i have tid of Thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, performance, pthreads

To get perf statistics of parallel running threads -

To get list of threads I use thread list in /proc/self/task

Now I want to get ID of a thread's CPU time clock. But clock_getcpuclockid only works with PIDs.

pthread_getcpuclockid requires the pthread id of thread and I did not find any way to get pthread id from TId of thread so I am looking for any alternative solution to this problem. CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID will return information of current only and I need information of all parallel threads. Any suggestions are welcome.

Is there any alternative to pthread_getcpuclockid? I wonder what pthread implementation does inside ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) & [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html). You probably want to use `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID`

See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

> Is there any alternative to `pthread_getcpuclockid?` I wonder what pthread implementation does inside ?

This is simple, and implementation specific (probably varies between [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) & [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/)). Most (AFAIK, all) [C standard libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) on Linux are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study their source code.

For musl-libc [src/threads/pthread_getcpuclockid.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread/pthread_getcpuclockid.c) is fetching the clock id from the data related to the `thread_t`

For GNU libc, I leave the diving into its source code to you.

Comment: passing CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID to clock_gettime will return information of current thread only. I need info of other parallel threads.

Comment: *clockid = (-t->tid-1)*8U + 6 looks interesting. is this platform independent ?

Comment: Very probably. And specific to `musl-libc` ; I won't be surprised if GNU `libc` NPTL implementation is doing different things; the lesson is : **dive** into the free software source code

Comment: Thanks a lot guy. here is same implementation without magic numbers https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/9d23e04/libc/bionic/pthread_getcpuclockid.cpp

Comment: That is probably a *different* implementation of the *same* function `pthread_getcpuclockid`